# Tiempo Apertura Formulario Tkinter Ejecutable .exe

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller

He realizado formularios en **Python** con **tkinter** y los vuelvo ejecutables con Pyinstaller para usarlos en computadores con Windows que no tienen python instalado, pero tengo un inconveniente con el tiempo de apertura de los formulario ya que generalmente oscila entre **3 y 5 minutos** por lo que me surge la siguiente duda ¿Hay forma de optimizar los ejecutables u otra alternativa para convertir los .py en ejecutables que me permita **reducir el tiempo de apertura de los formularios**?.

Comment: Si solo es al convertir a exe como supongo, ¿El exe lo creas en modo "one file"? En estos casos hay que descomprimir todo el exe en un archivo temporal antes de poder iniciar, lo cual añade una sobrecarga importante, especialmente en Windows que a veces las operaciones I/O son especialmente lentas, si además  si hay antivirus de por medio escamados con las DLL descomprimidas (XD) ya  ni hablamos,,,¿Además de tkinter usas otras bibliotecas externas?

Comment: @FJSevilla antes de convertirlo a exe el programa abre muy rápido, en Pycharm no tarda mas de 10 segundos, ¿Cómo puedo saber si son las operaciones I/O las que retrasan la apertura?.

Comment: ¿Creas el exe con la opción onefile?

Comment: @FJSevilla el exe si lo creo en modo "one file" así: 
(pyinstaller --onefile --icon.=/"nombre_logo.ico "script.py").
 Respecto a las bibliotecas adicionales uso pandas y datetime.

Comment: Crealo en modo --onedir y prueba a ver si hay una diferencia significativa en el tiempo de carga al evitar la descompresión en el fichero temporal. Pandas y sus dependencias (especialemnte NumPy) som bibliotecas complejas y de tamaño considerable, pueden ser la causa por lo comentado arriba...

Comment: @FJSevilla intentaré así, gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105926/discussion-between-fjsevilla-and-sebastian-espinosa-torres).

Comment: @FJSevilla retome hace poco el proyecto y al convertir el archivo .py a .exe con el comando --onedir efectivamente mejoró el tiempo de apertura ahora tarda entre 10 y 15 segundos, muchas gracias por tu ayuda.